# Prevent AWS CloudFormation from deleting DynamoDB using IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create an AWS Role which prevents CloudFormation delete a table. For instance, I created my table as follows:

```
UsersDynamoDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Description: Users DynamoDB Table
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: hashKey
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: rangeKey
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: hashKey
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: rangeKey
          KeyType: RANGE
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: index-rangeKey
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: rangeKey
              KeyType: HASH
            - AttributeName: hashKey
              KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: ALL
```

Now suppose that a develop accidentally delete this lines and update stack. This way the table with all its data would be removed. So I'd like to create a role which prevents CloudFormation delete DynamoDB tables. My first attempt was creating the Role below, but it didn't work.

```
PreventCloudFormationDeleteTableIAMRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: PreventTableDeletePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Deny
                Action:
                  - dynamodb:DeleteTable
                Resource:
                  - !Join
                    - '/'
                    - - !Join [':', ['arn:aws:dynamodb', !Sub '${AWS::Region}', '*', 'table']]
                      - !Join ['', [!Sub '${StackName}', '*']]
```

Am I missing some Role configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: How did you use this role? Did you pass it in when you created the stack?

Comment: Yes. I passed it on the same template I create the tables

Comment: When you create a stack you can specify a role arn for cloudformation to use when creating/updating/deleting resources. That role cannot of course be created by the stack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `DeletionPolicy` of `RETAIN` to prevent the table from being deleted when the stack is removed or table is removed from the template. Also the new `UpdateReplacePolicy` will prevent CloudFormation from deleting the table when it needs to do so due to primary key changes.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the role is properly attached to the invoking user/principal, is it possible that the policy Arn from that join does not match the table Arn?

Also consider retaining the resource instead of denying the operation: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB has launched a new feature: Deletion protection that disables a table deletion, irrespective of whether any AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) permissions policies allow deletion of the table.

More in:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.Basics.html?icmpid=docs_console_unmapped#WorkingWithTables.Basics.DeletionProtection